# .Net MVC print to network

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an application where users submit a request and I would like to print the request details to my printer as soon as a request comes in. I am using .Net MVC. Does anyone know of how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be able to print to any printer registered with the OS whether it is an ASP.NET MVC project or not. I think it would be the same as printing from any desktop application. There is a tutorial here, or just do a web search for printing in .NET: [http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44330-printing-in-c%23/](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44330-printing-in-c#/)

Comment: So the printer does not need to be shared?